# como hacer que dicho id que viene del boton se iguale con el del producto

Tags: javascript

como hacer para que dicho id sea == al id de los productos para asi saber si esta o no repetido
mis productos llegan a una tabla html con php y con php los recorro y desde hay mismo capturo el id para que este valla a mi funcion addToCarritoItem donde trato de hacer la igualacion del producto seleccionado con dicho id

intento de esta manera

```
   let itemProducto = Productos.id
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
 if(itemCarrito &&itemProducto==id){
```

lo que muestra en la imagen es el numero id y este debe ser leido en la fucion es 16 en el caso del ejemplo
[

```
function addToCarritoItem(id){
 let item = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
 if(item) {console.log("Repetido");
 }else console.log("NO Repetido");


  var id_ncap= document.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
  var idcap= document.querySelector('.id_prod').textContent

   var codigocap= document.querySelector('.codigo').textContent

let Productos = {
  id_n: id_ncap,
  id: idcap,
  codigo: codigocap,
  
};

   let itemProducto = Productos.id

  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
if(itemCarrito &&itemProducto==id){
   //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
  if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
    return;
  }
  itemCarrito.cantidad++;
   document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
}
else{
  itemCarrito = structuredClone(Productos); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
  itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
itemCarrito.precio=0;
  carrito.push(itemCarrito);

  //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
  //const carrito_content = document.querySelectorAll('#second-tab >.table  > 
  #carrito_content').textContent;
  console.log(carrito_content)
 carrito_content.innerHTML=itemProducto;
 }
 }
```